# Como fazer um cálculo de Raio em SQL, usando MySQL, com duas condições?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-select

Olá,

Já faço um cálculo de raio em SQL, utilizando MySQL e PHP, que pega a localização do aparelho (latitude e longitude) e filtra o raio de acordo com a localização do aparelho.

Ele é assim (trecho):

```
(6371 * acos(
        cos( radians('$latitude') )
        * cos( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( fornecedores.longitude ) - radians('$longitude') )
        + sin( radians('$latitude') )
        * sin( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) ) 
        )
    ) AS distancia
HAVING distancia <= '$raio'
```

Meu cliente agora quer que os fornecedores informem o raio que atuam, dentro de sua latitude e longitude. E quando o usuário definir um raio que possa pegar este fornecedor, porém este usuário estiver fora do raio de atuação do mesmo, ele não seja mostrado ao usuário.

Vou ter que criar um campo novo na tabela de fornecedores, pedindo o raio de atuação do mesmo (ali já tem sua latitude e longitude). E criar um novo cálculo, parecido com este a cima, porém filtrando por este raio de atuação.

Não estou sabendo como implementar mais este cálculo com esta condição.

Segue meu SQL completo, nele é o atual, sem o novo campo que terei que criar:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        (select avg(avaliacao.avaliacao_geral) from avaliacao where avaliacao.cod_fornecedor = fornecedores.cod_fornecedor ) as media_avaliacao,
   fornecedores.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedores.fantasia,
   fornecedores.CPF,
   fornecedores.identidade,
   fornecedores.email,
   fornecedores.cep,
   fornecedores.logradourro,
   fornecedores.complemento,
   fornecedores.cidade,
   fornecedores.estado,
   fornecedores.responsavel_contato,
   fornecedores.telefone_empresa,
   fornecedores.telefone_responsavel,
   fornecedores.celular,
   fornecedores.bairro,
   fornecedores.numero,
   fornecedores.latitude,
   fornecedores.longitude,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_oferta,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_fornecedor,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_categoria_com,
   cadastra_oferta.titulo_promocao,
   cadastra_oferta.descricao,
   cadastra_oferta.foto,
   cadastra_oferta.valor_sem_desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.valor_com_desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.validade_oferta,
   cadastra_oferta.igredientes,
   cadastra_oferta.qtd_estoque,
   categoria_comida.cod_categoria_com,
   categoria_comida.nome,
   categoria_comida.data_cadastro,
   fornecedor_credito.cod_fornecedor_codigo,
   fornecedor_credito.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedor_credito.qtd_credito,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.cod_configura_frete,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.tem_delivery,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.custo_padrao,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.frete_gratis,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.valor_minimo_frete_gratis,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.tipos_pagamentos,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.prazo_entrega_min,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.prazo_entrega_max,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.agenda_comida,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_one,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_two,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_three,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_four,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_five,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_six,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_seven,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_one,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_one,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_two,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_two,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_three,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_three,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_four,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_four,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_five,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_five,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_six,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_six,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_seven,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_seven,
   fornecedor_visual.cod_fornecedor_visual,
   fornecedor_visual.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedor_visual.descricao_empresa,
   fornecedor_visual.facebook,
   fornecedor_visual.localizacao_mapa,
   fornecedor_visual.logomarca,
   fornecedor_visual.data_cadastro,
   fornecedor_visual.latitude,
   fornecedor_visual.longitude,
   (6371 * acos(
        cos( radians('$latitude') )
        * cos( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( fornecedores.longitude ) - radians('$longitude') )
        + sin( radians('$latitude') )
        * sin( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) ) 
        )
    ) AS distancia

FROM   
   fornecedores INNER JOIN cadastra_oferta ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = cadastra_oferta.cod_fornecedor
   INNER JOIN categoria_comida ON cadastra_oferta.cod_categoria_com = categoria_comida.cod_categoria_com
   INNER JOIN fornecedor_credito ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = fornecedor_credito.cod_fornecedor
   INNER JOIN fornecedor_configura_frete ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = fornecedor_configura_frete.cod_fornecedor
   INNER JOIN fornecedor_visual ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = fornecedor_visual.cod_fornecedor     
WHERE 
   (fornecedor_credito.qtd_credito >= '1') AND
   (cadastra_oferta.qtd_estoque >= '1')  AND
   (cadastra_oferta.validade_oferta >= NOW()) 
HAVING distancia <= '$raio'
ORDER BY
   cadastra_oferta.titulo_promocao ASC";
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma e parece estar funcionando.

1. Criei um novo campo, na tabela fornecedor_configura_frete chamado raio_atuacao, aproveitei o que estava certo no filtro de localização do usuário e mudei apenas os parâmetros e acrescentei mais uma condição:

   ```
   (6371 * acos(
       cos( radians('$latitude') )
       * cos( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) )
       * cos( radians( fornecedores.longitude ) - radians('$longitude') )
       + sin( radians('$latitude') )
       * sin( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) ) 
       )
   ) AS distancia,
   (6371 * acos(
       cos( radians(fornecedores.latitude) )
       * cos( radians( '$latitude' ) )
       * cos( radians( '$longitude' ) - radians(fornecedores.longitude) )
       + sin( radians(fornecedores.latitude) )
       * sin( radians( '$latitude' ) ) 
       )
   ) AS distancia_fornecedor
   HAVING distancia <= '$raio' AND distancia_fornecedor <= fornecedor_configura_frete.raio_atuacao
   ```

Ficando o SQL completo desta forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        (select avg(avaliacao.avaliacao_geral) from avaliacao where avaliacao.cod_fornecedor = fornecedores.cod_fornecedor ) as media_avaliacao,
   fornecedores.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedores.fantasia,
   fornecedores.CPF,
   fornecedores.identidade,
   fornecedores.email,
   fornecedores.cep,
   fornecedores.logradourro,
   fornecedores.complemento,
   fornecedores.cidade,
   fornecedores.estado,
   fornecedores.responsavel_contato,
   fornecedores.telefone_empresa,
   fornecedores.telefone_responsavel,
   fornecedores.celular,
   fornecedores.bairro,
   fornecedores.numero,
   fornecedores.latitude,
   fornecedores.longitude,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_oferta,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_fornecedor,
   cadastra_oferta.cod_categoria_com,
   cadastra_oferta.titulo_promocao,
   cadastra_oferta.descricao,
   cadastra_oferta.foto,
   cadastra_oferta.valor_sem_desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.valor_com_desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.desconto,
   cadastra_oferta.validade_oferta,
   cadastra_oferta.igredientes,
   cadastra_oferta.qtd_estoque,
   categoria_comida.cod_categoria_com,
   categoria_comida.nome,
   categoria_comida.data_cadastro,
   fornecedor_credito.cod_fornecedor_codigo,
   fornecedor_credito.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedor_credito.qtd_credito,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.cod_configura_frete,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.tem_delivery,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.custo_padrao,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.frete_gratis,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.valor_minimo_frete_gratis,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.tipos_pagamentos,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.prazo_entrega_min,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.prazo_entrega_max,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.agenda_comida,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.raio_atuacao,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_one,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_two,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_three,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_four,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_five,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_six,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.dayw_seven,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_one,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_one,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_two,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_two,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_three,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_three,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_four,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_four,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_five,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_five,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_six,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_six,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_ini_seven,
   fornecedor_configura_frete.hour_end_seven,
   fornecedor_visual.cod_fornecedor_visual,
   fornecedor_visual.cod_fornecedor,
   fornecedor_visual.descricao_empresa,
   fornecedor_visual.facebook,
   fornecedor_visual.localizacao_mapa,
   fornecedor_visual.logomarca,
   fornecedor_visual.data_cadastro,
   fornecedor_visual.latitude,
   fornecedor_visual.longitude,
   (6371 * acos(
        cos( radians('$latitude') )
        * cos( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( fornecedores.longitude ) - radians('$longitude') )
        + sin( radians('$latitude') )
        * sin( radians( fornecedores.latitude ) ) 
        )
    ) AS distancia,
    (6371 * acos(
        cos( radians(fornecedores.latitude) )
        * cos( radians( '$latitude' ) )
        * cos( radians( '$longitude' ) - radians(fornecedores.longitude) )
        + sin( radians(fornecedores.latitude) )
        * sin( radians( '$latitude' ) ) 
        )
    ) AS distancia_fornecedor
FROM   
   fornecedores INNER JOIN cadastra_oferta ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = cadastra_oferta.cod_fornecedor
   INNER JOIN categoria_comida ON cadastra_oferta.cod_categoria_com = categoria_comida.cod_categoria_com
   INNER JOIN fornecedor_credito ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = fornecedor_credito.cod_fornecedor
   INNER JOIN fornecedor_configura_frete ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = fornecedor_configura_frete.cod_fornecedor
   INNER JOIN fornecedor_visual ON fornecedores.cod_fornecedor = fornecedor_visual.cod_fornecedor     
WHERE 
   (fornecedor_credito.qtd_credito >= '1') AND
   (cadastra_oferta.qtd_estoque >= '1')  AND
   (cadastra_oferta.validade_oferta >= NOW()) 
HAVING distancia <= '$raio' AND distancia_fornecedor <= fornecedor_configura_frete.raio_atuacao
ORDER BY
   cadastra_oferta.titulo_promocao ASC";
```

Fiz alguns testes aqui e parece estar funcionando perfeitamente.